# IntelliJ: cannot resolve symbol when class is present under build folder created after compiling project

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

IntelliJ complaining about class which is present in project directory, though project is building ok. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: File | Invalidate Caches?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried but this did not fix the problem, build folder (orange), shown in snapshot, is currently excluded from the source in project settings, I also tried adding this to source in project settings but it also did not work.

Comment: Why do you keep source files in the output directory?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I am using Java annotation processing which generates additional files during compile time in build folder.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has the special source root type for this case: generated sources. .class files generated into the output directory are not used by the IDE for resolve since this directory is not a part of the project classpath (it's even excluded by default for the performance reasons).